# Is it possible to get a view's initial size in NIB file BEFORE adding is as subview?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nib, viewcontroller

I have a nib-based view controller owning a view. Is it possible to get the initial specified size of the view in that nib file as soon as the view controller's **- initWithNibFile:bundle:** called?

Comment: Sorry, problem solved. Just read the view's **-frame**. Could I remove this question?

Comment: Just flagged your question. Moderators, probably, will take care of it.